# What are the differences in Ragnarok PvP on Private Servers and Retail Servers?

Tags: ragnarok-online

I've heard that it's better on private servers from some friends but this conflicts with me as a WoW player. In WoW, it's common knowledge that PvP on retail is better than on private server.

What are the differences between PvP on private and retail servers?

Comment: this question seems very subjective

Comment: In it's current form, it is impossible for anyone to answer this question. For starters, what exactly do you mean by "better"? I would also assume that each private server differs from other private servers, due to this I fail to see how someone could make the claim that private servers are "better" when it would vary from server to server.

Comment: Feel free to flag and ask for re-open when and if the question gets fixed.

Comment: @Juan I edited the question to ask about the differences, which I think the existing answer actually addresses pretty well.  Voting to reopen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If what you're looking for is a balanced PvP, probably the retail server wins. However, Ragnarok is highly dependant on gear, cards etc, so basically the older the player is on the server, the better he is on PvP, considering equal skill. On retail, that difference can be huge (like a royal guard with Tao Gunka card); on private servers maybe that don't matter so much, because getting gear/cards is easier (again, depends on rates).

Usually, private servers have smaller communities, and the PvP is more personal, with friends, allies, vendettas etc. In retail, with more people, there's more battlegrounds, it's less to-the-heart PvP.

Comment: I felt this answer was not very informative.

Comment: "What are the differences between PvP on private and retail servers?" was the question, not the difference between Private and Retail in general.

Answer (score 2):

It depends a lot on the server like for example [Existence Ragnarok Online](http://www.existencero.com) uses its own unique PvP system which track's player's kills and gives them an aura which other players can see to warn them the person is dangerous and has been killing too much. As the points scale the aura color changes:

> Red Aura 100-199
>
> Blue Aura 200-299
>
> Black Aura 300+

When a player hits 300+ and is killed by another player, it is possible that they could drop some items and they are sent directly to jail where they have to wait for points to drop, or bribe the jailer to let them out early. Player's who have killed too many players can hide in the market or paradise island and wait for their points to drop.

Players who pk others get experience and part of another players money that they are carrying people that kill others who have been killing too much gain a higher rate of experience and money.

Money which is given to the person going around pking others is automatically set into a bounty system over that players name. In the future others will be able to take a quest to kill that player and can claim the reward for doing so.

As you can see this is a specific type of PvP. Not your average PvP you would find in retail, nor most private servers because it is highly customized.

Answer (score 1):

Each private server is different, and each person has their own idea of what "better" is, so I'll just elaborate on possible differences between the two. Also, keep in mind that private servers can be customized in **any number of infinite ways**.

Here's a list of all the different customizations I have experienced that have a bearing on PVP:

- customized drop rates (can go in any direction, easier or harder to obtain gear)
- customized experience rates (faster leveling)
- changed level caps
- changed skill point caps
- custom equips
- changed or added skills
- added classes (eg, third classes even though it wasn't official at the time)
- possible mandatory/forced homunculus AI
- different PVP maps
- different PVP events
- different player sprites and sizes and even morphing into a world monster
- PVP forced/denied on some/all normal world maps (eg, some servers have a "PVP everywhere" world)
- customized auto unequip & refuse to put on some equipments in PVP
- different/customized WoE versions
- possibly limited quantities of potting
- possibly more inexperienced players in PVP
- different PVP "play styles" and strategies from all of the above
- different sized player populations

Again, this is not meant to decide which is "better" but only elaborate on some things that can happen. It's left to the player to decide which severs and features suit their fancy. Because of the sheer quantity of available customizations, chances are that there's always a server the player might like better than the one he is currently at.